# how could I modify the mysql update method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to update mysql table from a dto list, but there is some exception, something like grammer issue, here is my code:

```
@Override
  @Transactional
  public void updateCustomCategory(List<ItemDto> itemDtoList) {
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(itemDtoList)) {
      for (ItemDto itemDto : itemDtoList) {
        Long l1CustomCategoryId = itemDto.getL1CustomCatId();
        Long l2CustomCategoyId = itemDto.getL2CustomCatId();
        StringBuilder query =
                new StringBuilder(
                        "update ItemDto item set item.l1CustomCategoryId = :l1CustomCategoryId and item.l2CustomCategoryId = :l2CustomCategoyId where itemId = :itemId");
        Query q = this.em.createQuery(query.toString());
        q.setParameter("l1CustomCategoryId", l1CustomCategoryId);
        q.setParameter("l2CustomCategoyId", l2CustomCategoyId);
        q.setParameter("itemId", itemDto.getItemId());
        q.executeUpdate();
      }
    }
  }
```

and exception as below:

```
2019-10-04 14:49:00.227 ERROR 11909 --- [nio-9092-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: and near line 1, column 108 [update com.shopee.data.dto.brandseller.item.ItemDto item set item.l1CustomCategoryId = :l1CustomCategoryId and item.l2CustomCategoryId = :l2CustomCategoyId where itemId = :itemId]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: and near line 1, column 108 [update com.shopee.data.dto.brandseller.item.ItemDto item set item.l1CustomCategoryId = :l1CustomCategoryId and item.l2CustomCategoryId = :l2CustomCategoyId where itemId = :itemId]] with root cause

    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: and near line 1, column 108 [update com.shopee.data.dto.brandseller.item.ItemDto item set item.l1CustomCategoryId = :l1CustomCategoryId and item.l2CustomCategoryId = :l2CustomCategoyId where itemId = :itemId]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker.throwQueryException(ErrorTracker.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:296) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile
```

Comment: Try to put a comma `,` instead of an `and` in your query .

Comment: can you add your ItemDto code

Comment: @Arnaud that's correct, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use `AND` with `SET`, you separate them with commas. The correct syntax is

`SET item.l1CustomCategoryId = :l1CustomCategoryId, item.l2CustomCategoryId = :l2CustomCategoyId`